# Not able to pass variable value in sampler's HTTP request which is created using groovy scripting in JSR223 Preprocessor in Jmeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter, preprocessor, jsr223

I'm trying to create a hash using groovy script in JSR223 Preprocessor and then pass it to the parent HTTP request's body data, but i'm not sure where I'm doing it wrong. When I have one HTTP request in the thread group then it doesn't work but if it has two HTTP requests then it works for the second request.
Note: Variable HASH is being set after the first request. Though I've tried preprocessor to be the child of first HTTP request or putting it into thread group before HTTP request but nothing works.

**Script data:**

```
import java.security.MessageDigest
def requestBody = sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue()
def data = new XmlParser().parseText(requestBody)
String method=data.method.text()
String token=data.token.text()
String time=data.time.text()
String xyz ='method'+method+'token'+token+'time'+time+'3VDEY-6ZHLH-D27C0-T2ALI'
String hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(xyz.bytes).encodeHex().toString()
vars.put("HASH", hash)
```

**HTTP request body data:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <method>ping</method>
    <token>-</token>
    <time>1575542978</time>
    <signature>${HASH}</signature>
    <params/>
</root>
```

**Test plan Images**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vGbwyDo8eWUDL7EDZlK8bdbApxtFpWGT/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Us6tSuRw6MJ__YrnX0tTCKL8S9QSgp-v/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10hobprJcga6_y23VWd5U3X1aaSEXzGkb/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a bug in JMeter, I would suggest raising an issue via [JMeter Bugzilla](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html)

In the meantime you can proceed by replacing the [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) directly in the request body and substituting the "old" request body with the newly generated hash.

Suggested code amendment:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest
def requestBody = sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue()
def data = new XmlParser().parseText(requestBody)
String method=data.method.text()
String token=data.token.text()
String time=data.time.text()
String xyz ='method'+method+'token'+token+'time'+time+'3VDEY-6ZHLH-D27C0-T2ALI'
String hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(xyz.bytes).encodeHex().toString()
requestBody = requestBody.replace('${HASH}', hash)
def args = new org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments()
sampler.setArguments(args)
sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('', requestBody, '')
sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to provide a screenshot or textual representation of your test plan tree since I suspect that you are having an issue with scope here.

As a workaround you could replace the JSR223 PreProcessor with a JSR223 Sampler and place it in the correct order into your test plan. To avoid that sampler showing up in your results you can attach a JSR223 PostProcessor with `prev.setIgnore()`

Comment: Hi I've shared the images in the links above

Comment: Okay. I'm lost here. It works for me with a minimal example and JMeter 5.1.1. 

Body: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <signature>${HASH}</signature>
</root>`

PreProcessor: `vars.put("HASH", "some_processed_hash")`

yields the expected Request Body:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <signature>some_processed_hash</signature>
</root>`